# How to have the WolframAlpha command process generated numbers without having to cut-and-paste

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I often generate long decimal expansions of various numbers.Then I cut-and-paste them into the == command to get a WolframAlpha analysis (to see if there are any interesting properties, possible "explanations",...).

So, say, "x" is the number. How can I DIRECTLY apply the WolframAlpha command to it, without having to do (it would seem) extra cutting-and-pasting? A basic question it would seem (that a few attempts of mine to address have not yet succeeded.)

Comment: `WolframAlpha@"x"`

Answer (score 1):

Say, the number is

```
x = N[Sqrt[2], 100]
```

Then you can use [`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) as

```
WolframAlpha@ToString[x]
```

[image]